# Angular directive only applying to last element of an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, angularjs-directive, dom-events

In my Angular project, I tried creating a `directive` that will resize the element's width dynamically when the browser window is resized. To test it out, I created the code below:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('ftagn')
        .directive('dynamicWidth', dynamicWidthDirective);

    dynamicWidthDirective.$inject = [];

    function dynamicWidthDirective( $window ) {
        var directive = {
            link: link,
            restrict: 'A'
        };
        return directive;

        function link(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(window)
            window.onresize = function(event) {
                element[ 0 ].style.width = '500px';
            };
        }
    }
})();
```

While the element style of `500px` width is indeed being applied on window resize, it's only being applied to the last element of an `ng-repeat`, which is the following one:

```
<div class="card" dynamic-width ng-repeat="fruit in $ctrl.fruits" >
    <div>{{fruit}}</div>
</div>
```

It looks as if each successive iteration of the directive is overwriting the previous one.

How can I ensure that all elements will be resized and not just the last one?

Comment: this will be taken care if you are using bootstrap! why a separate directive for it?

Comment: If you're referring to bootstrap's grid system, that is not what I intend to use. This is more of an experiment of mine with attribute directives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`window.onresize` event will get register only once, that's only last row `resize` event is getting register on `window` object.

Rather use `$(window).resize` which can take collection of events of desired element.

```
$(window).resize(function(event) {
    element[ 0 ].style.width = '500px';
});
```

> **Note:** This could be a bad in terms of performance, as if there are more than 1k records can put 1k `resize` event register on.

For the same you should consider unbind the event once row gets removed. That could avoid memory leaking issue. Also use `$window` instead of `window`(Make sure you inject `$window` in directive function)

```
var w = angular.element($window);
var resizer= function(event) {
    element[0].style.width = '500px';
};
w.resize(resizer);
scope.$on('$destroy', function(event){
   w.off('resize', resizer)
})
```

Comment: Do i need to inject `$window` into the directive?

Comment: @Tiago. No need since window is javascript global variable, you can use it anywhere, just wrapped it with $ like an above answer unless you want to  do it in angular way. Just inject $window.

Comment: @Tiago thanks for the tip, I was editing the answer for more insights on it, in performance point of view... deregisteration of event is another aspect could stop memory leaking..

Comment: I'm getting `Cannot read property 'resize' of undefined` when using `$window`. How can I inject it properly in the `link` function?

Comment: @Tiago take a look at my edit **1.** do inject $window in directive function **2** do wrap `$window` with `angular.element`

Comment: Hmm, trying the optimized code above, the `resizer` function is never getting called. Even when I resize the browser window.

Comment: @Tiago it should work.. I did a simple change.. can you create a plunker..??

Comment: Aha, It works! I forgot to also inject `$window` on `dynamicWidthDirective.$inject = [];` as you can see on my snippet above.

Comment: Thank you for all the help @Pankaj Parkar.